# Identify that a page is a grandchild page

Tags: pages

How do I identify that a page is a grandchild page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use get_page twice like this handy little function

```
function get_grandpapa($page_id){
    $current_page = get_page( $page_id );
    if ($current_page->post_parent > 0){
        //has at least a parent
        $parent_page = get_page($current_page->post_parent);
        if ($parent_page->post_parent > 0){
            return $parent_page->post_parent;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function returns the grandparent page ID or false if there is no grandparent.

Comment: Why thank you! I had to Booleanate the function (renamed to is_grandchild) and changed line 7 to "return true".